# How to find rows count of groups?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, count, group-by

I am creating one Stored Procedure in SQL and i am in trouble to find count using grouping.

This is my database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE InputCurr (
  [InputCurrID] int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  [Date] datetime NULL,
  [OpCurrencyName] decimal(18, 8) NULL,
  [IpCurrencyName] varchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
  [Count] int NULL,
)
```

**Datavalues:**

```
insert into InputCurr ( Date,OpCurrencyName,IpCurrencyName ) values ('1/1/2013','US','$');
insert into InputCurr ( Date,OpCurrencyName,IpCurrencyName ) values ('1/2/2013','US','$');
insert into InputCurr ( Date,OpCurrencyName,IpCurrencyName ) values ('1/3/2013','UK','#');
insert into InputCurr ( Date,OpCurrencyName,IpCurrencyName ) values ('1/4/2013','US','$');
insert into InputCurr ( Date,OpCurrencyName,IpCurrencyName ) values ('1/5/2013','US','$');
```

I use the following SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getCurrencyReportFiels
AS
BEGIN
SELECT InputCurrID,Date,OpCurrencyName,IpCurrencyName,Count=(COUNT(*))
FROM InputCurr
GROUP BY InputCurrID,date,OpCurrencyName,IpCurrencyName
END
```

I am getting O/p like this:

```
InputCurrID    Date       OpCurrencyName      IpCurrencyName     Count
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      1        1/1/2013       US                   $               1 <--here i want count of grouping by OpCurrencyName & IpCurrencyName
      2        1/2/2013       US                   $               1 <--here i want count of grouping by OpCurrencyName & IpCurrencyName
      3        1/3/2013       UK                   #               1
      4        1/4/2013       US                   $               1<--here i want count of grouping by OpCurrencyName & IpCurrencyName
      5        1/5/2013       US                   $               1<--here i want count of grouping by OpCurrencyName & IpCurrencyName
```

Now, i want output like this...

```
InputCurrID    Date       OpCurrencyName      IpCurrencyName     Count
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      1        1/1/2013       US                   $               4  
      2        1/2/2013       US                   $               4 
      3        1/3/2013       UK                   #               1
      4        1/4/2013       US                   $               4
      5        1/5/2013       US                   $               4
```

Comment: What do you actually want to group by? All transactions with the same currencies that happened on the same day?  Also, what sql server version are you using?

Comment: i want group by OpCurrencyName,IpCurrencyName in 1 month. if currency change then we need to count as per OpCurrencyName,IpCurrencyName. In e.g i have 5 days in month and there is '1/3/2013' transaction done with UK , # so we count that seperatly. and i am usin sql server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
WITH Groups
AS
(
  SELECT 
    OpCurrencyName, 
    IpCurrencyName,
    Count=(COUNT(*))
  FROM InputCurr
  GROUP BY OpCurrencyName,IpCurrencyName
) 
SELECT 
  i.InputCurrID, 
  i.Date, 
  g.OpCurrencyName, 
  g.IpCurrencyName,
  g.Count
FROM InputCurr i
INNER JOIN Groups g  ON i.OpCurrencyName = g.OpCurrencyName
                    AND i.IpCurrencyName = g.IpCurrencyName
ORDER BY i.InputCurrID;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c46cc/5)

This will give you:

```
| INPUTCURRID |                           DATE | OPCURRENCYNAME | IPCURRENCYNAME | COUNT |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|           1 | January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |             US |              $ |     4 |
|           2 | January, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 |             US |              $ |     4 |
|           3 | January, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 |             UK |              # |     1 |
|           4 | January, 04 2013 00:00:00+0000 |             US |              $ |     4 |
|           5 | January, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000 |             US |              $ |     4 |
```

You can write it without a CTE, using a subquery or with a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT InputCurrID,Date,OpCurrencyName,IpCurrencyName
,(Select Count(*) from InputCurr c2 where c2.OpCurrencyName=InputCurr.OpCurrencyName) as [Count]
FROM InputCurr
Order by InputCurrID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select [InputCurrID],
   [Date],
   [OpCurrencyName],
   [IpCurrencyName],
   count(*) over (partition by [OpCurrencyName],[IpCurrencyName])
from [InputCurr]
order by [InputCurrID]
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a32d/2)